# when dropdown value is selected, show the status in textbox

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

I have a function where I add shops. In this function, I can select whether the shop is **OPEN** or **CLOSE**. My target is, on my other modal,

> when I create a user and selected the shop I created, The status of
> the shop whether OPEN or CLOSE will appear on my textbox.

I provided my codes below and my screenshot. Any help will be appreciated

[image]

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-md-3 float-left mb-2" >
               <button type="button" class=" btn-block btn bbutton  text-bold btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#accountModal" 
    data-id="<?php echo $_SESSION['uid']?>" data-user="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>" 
                Edit <?php echo $_SESSION['uid']?>>
                Add User &emsp;
                </button> 


  <div class="modal fade" id="accountModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #00e6ac, #1f9388);">
                <h5 class="modal-title text-bold" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Users For shop</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                
             </div>
            
            <div class="modal-body bg-white">
              <form id="createAccount"> 
               <div class="form-group" >
                <label>Company</label>
                  <select class="form-control" name="nameofshop" required>
                        <option value="">No Selected</option>
                        <?php 
                        foreach($category as $row):?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row->shopName;?>"><?php echo $row->shopName;?></option>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    
                     <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="exampleInputEmail1">status:</label>
                         <label class="container">Open
                          <input type="radio"  name="status" value="open">
                   
                        </label>
                        <label class="container">Close
                          <input type="radio" name="status" value="close">
                
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    

              
                    </div>
           
                    
                    
                   
                    
                
                   
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn btn-dark btn-flat float-right" value="">Submit</button>
            </form>
            </div>
           
            

         
            </div>
            
        </div>
        

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would listen to any change in the shop input field using javascript. Whenever an option is selected, I would take that option's value (let's say "icecreamshop" for instance), and get the status of that shop from the model. When you finally get that "close" status, you can then insert it manually into the second input field.

An example using jQuery:

```
let shopField = $('#shop-field');
let statusField = $('#status-field');

shopField.change(() => {
   let status = findShopStatus($(this).val());
   statusField.val(status);
});
```

where findShopStatus is a function that gets the status of a shop by its name from the model.